# How can I format SSMS query results for easy copy and pasting?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm using SET NOCOUNT ON and I unchecked "Include column headers in the result set", but I'm still getting the dashes delimeter:

```
1222

------

12234

------

000033

-------
```

All I want is a vertical list of numbers with no line breaks. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Presumably this is 3 statements? If they are of compatible types & the columns match - `select 123 union all select 456 union all select 999` or insert the data into a #temp table then select from that at the end

Comment: Thanks, I used a temp table. Please post as answer so I may accept.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably this is 3 statements?

If they are of compatible types & the columns match you can combine them with `union`:

`select 123 union all select 456 union all select 999`

Alternatively insert the data into a `#temp` table then select from that at the end.